# Ionic 4 Rest api calls not working on the Device with and without proxy. Getting Unknown error

Tags: android, angular, ionic4

Ionic 4 app not working on device all API calls are saying unknown error
working perfectly on ionic serve

Tried

1. Updated the `config.xml` with allowed and access tags
2. updated API to allow access from same origin
3. Updated the cordova plugins nothing
   seems working 4, Added to index file

Config.xml

```
<preference name="CordovaWebViewEngine" value="CDVWKWebViewEngine" />
 <access origin="*" />
   <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" /
```

index.html

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="img-src 'self' data:; default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
```

Nothing seems working
[image]

```
Cordova:

   cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)
   Cordova Platforms     : android 7.1.4
   Cordova Plugins       : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 3.0.0, (and 7 other plugins)

System:

   NodeJS : v10.7.0 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm    : 5.3.0
   OS     : Windows 10

ionic (Ionic CLI)             : 4.6.0
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.0.0-beta.7
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.7.5
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 0.7.5
   @angular/cli                  : 6.1.5
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : not installed
```

Comment: Please update your answer. 
1. On which platform is the error thrown? 
2. Are you running the app in livereload?
3. Show how did you configure the proxy (if so).

Comment: Im deploying to android platform and running directly with ionic cordova run on emulator

Comment: Even progressive web app is not able to reach api Please help im  totally stuck

Comment: Sure I will try to help you, lets dig into the problem deeper. 
1. I usually receive error with "Status: 0" when there is no internet connection, please check you do have.
2. Enable CORS from your server
3. Upload your code on some version-control tool if you can.

Comment: https://learnerapp.visualstudio.com/LearnerApp/_git/LearnerApp    Credentials omkarachary Omk@r123

Comment: Username :omkarachary@outlook.com password Omk@r123